# I need some explanation on the percentage sign operator

Tags: php

I've taken this chunk of code from php.net but i need explanation on what the percentage sign is doing. I've changed the year a few times and get new results but it all seems very random.

```
<?php
    function getChineseZodiac($year){

        switch ($year % 12) :
            case  0: return 'Monkey';  // Years 0, 12, 1200, 2004...
            case  1: return 'Rooster';
            case  2: return 'Dog';
            case  3: return 'Boar';
            case  4: return 'Rat';
            case  5: return 'Ox';
            case  6: return 'Tiger';
            case  7: return 'Rabit';
            case  8: return 'Dragon';
            case  9: return 'Snake';
            case 10: return 'Horse';
            case 11: return 'Lamb';
        endswitch;
    }

    echo getChineseZodiac(2016);
    ?>
```

I've read that it's a Modulus operator and is for the remainder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just wanted to add that since you're learning php, you will stumble upon a bunch of weird symbols used in a whole variety of ways, some of these symbols will be used twice under different circumstances that yield to different outcomes. To avoid confusion, have this page as a reference, it will be your best friend!

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mod operator returns the remainder of the division.

Eg. `7 % 3` is 1 because after you `divide 7 by 3` the remaining whole number is 1

In the code above

```
2004/12 = 167
```

but the reminder of the division is 0, since 2004 is perfectly divisible by 12.

So

```
2004 % 12 = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The intent here is to "wrap around" at the 12, so that you get a sequence which repeats every 12 years.

The remainder (modulus) operator is commonly used in this way. If you start with year 11, `$year % 12` will return the remainder of 11 / 12 which is of course 11, so the value is unchanged. However, starting with year 12 the number will wrap back around: The remainder of 12/12 is 0, the remainder of 13/12 is 1 and so on.

As a result, `$year % 12` keeps cycling through the numbers 0 through 11 for consecutive years, just as the years cycle through the chinese zodiac.